# UNIX timestamp TO Google bigQuery TS Format

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using google Pub/sub to receive a message and trigger a cloud func, that func queries the data of the message in BigQuery, the problem is that in my message I receive UNIX timestamp, and I need to convert this time stamp for bigquery format, otherwise the function can not run my query...

In this part of the function:

```
exports.insertBigQuery = async (message, context) => {
  // Decode base64 the PubSub message
  let logData = Buffer.from(message.data, "base64").toString();
  // Convert it in JSON
  let logMessage = JSON.parse(logData);

  const query = createQuery(logMessage);

  const options = {
    query: query,
    location: "US",
  };

  const [job] = await bigquery.createQueryJob(options);
  console.log(`Job ${job.id} started.`);

  // Only wait the end of the job. Theere is no row as answer, it's only an insert
  await job.getQueryResults();
};
```

I access the data in the message.

On this part of the function I query in my bigquery:

```
function createQuery() {
  const queryString = `INSERT INTO \`mytable\`(myTS, userTS, registerTS) 
VALUES ( @myTS, @userTS, @registerTS);`;
```

My problem is that I receive the message with UNIX time stamp and when the function runs my query gives me an error. I couldn't find any solution, any help is MUCH appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you cand handle this is using the `TIMESTAMP_SECONDS` function to wrap your values on the insert

```
INSERT INTO \`mytable\`(myTS, userTS, registerTS) 
VALUES ( TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(@myTS), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(@userTS), TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(@registerTS));
```

Comment: Perfect solution! Thank you very much @Daniel Zagales! May I ask you how to do the inverse? I mean, I'll use the query to call API later, how can I transform BigQuery timestamp in UNIX timestamp again? Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: You should just be able to use the `UNIX_SECONDS` function
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#unix_seconds